# Data separation for Time Series Models? (both Statistical and ML)

Tags: time-series, data, statistics, historical-data

I had a big question about data slicing for Time-Series model fitting. In university, since I wasn't a stats major, so I didn't do much model fitting for data, other than my ML class, and have *ZERO education on time-series*

In that class, I was (and am still building) a model to predict trading signals (buy = upward movement >1 (rolling) std deviation, sell = downward movement >1 (rolling) std deviation, hold = neither)

In that project, I started by using data "slicing" wherein I just split up the N data points into a [M, N/M] series of prices, then I was suggested by a TA to use an M-wide sliding window method to segment the N data points into a series of [M, N-M] sequences of prices (which I did).

*Now, I'm trying to (re)develop my understanding of all relevant time series models, including:* AR/MA/ARMA/ARIMA/SARIMA/SARIMAX, Exponential Smoothing methods, ARCH/GARCH/QARCH, and redevelop my knowledge of Recurrent Neural Networks (and possibly Transformers).

**My question is even starting with AR/MA models, are there relevant times where you would ever "slice" the time series data instead of using sliding window techniques? If so when/why?** (One theory I have is that since RNN's/Transformers "remember" past data, using slicing is just as adequate as using a sliding window.

Picture [Explanation Here](https://prnt.sc/dBHn61iLGvGi)

Any help and or resources for learning time series would be appreciated, as of right now I'm using YT/Wikipedia/MathStackXchange